# Trendy sticked picture gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, gallery

We often see this kind of gallery these days :

http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/index.php?theme=dreamspa (go to gallery)
http://joomla.templaza.net/fitness/index.php/gallery?limitstart=0

I think it looks kinda good and i would like to add something like this to a website. I don't have a lot of knowledge in javascript, so does someone have a sample, tutorial, link, code, or anything to help me to achieve this ?

My website was created using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/?s=gallery&search-type=posts) are some 'trendy' gallery ideas, they include a download to the code so it is kinda plug and play. Best to reference the source though.

Comment: Wow some of them are very nice. I used bootstrap to create the website. I forgot to tell it.